# Time needed to board Sandefjord-Stromstad ferry on foot

Tags: ferries, sweden, norway

I am taking a ferry (Color Line, MS Color Viking) from Sandefjord (Norway) to Stromstad (Sweden). We will be two people with no car and minimal luggage (we arrive to Sandefjord Torp airport with hand luggage only). Is getting on the ferry in such case simply walking in and showing the ticket, or is there any more complicated procedure to go through? How long before the departure should we turn up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://www.colorline.com/practical-information/the-terminal-in-sandefjord

> All passengers must be available for check in no later than 30 minutes
>   before departure.

[Airport to ferry terminal](https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g226938-i5308-k3564200-Sandefjord_airport_to_Color_Line_terminal-Sandefjord_Sandefjord_Municipality_Vestfold_Easte.html):

> There is a shuttle bus to the train station [i]n Torp, then take the
>   train to Sandefjord and walk to the terminal, 5-10 min walk[.]

Comment: thanks, I already have the bus + train ticket from airport to the city, arriving to Sandefjord station about 45 minutes before the ferry, so seems we have to walk straight to the harbor but won't need to run :)